# How to identify the navbar colour in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

Currently, the sticky navigation on my WordPress site is transparent on the homepage and a white background on the other pages. I've tried copying sections from this CSS into my child theme style.css file and changing the hex codes but i can't identify the section of code that i need to change the colour.

Transparent:
[image]

White:
[image]

After editing .container:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClZb1.png)

```html
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav > li > a:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        width: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #00aff2;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        transition: all 1s;
    }
    .nav > li:hover > a:before {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .shrink .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .navbar-nav li:hover .dropdown-menu{
        visibility:visible;
        border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    #site-navigation .container{
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-center .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar-center .menu-container {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .admin-bar #site-navigation.shrink {
        top: 32px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav > li.active > a:after, .current-page-parent:after {
        height: 0 !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .navbar-nav a:hover, .navbar-nav a:focus {
        color: #ffffff !important;
        background-color: #000 !important;
    }
    .menu-container {
        width: 70%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        top: 100%;
    }
    .openNav .menu-container {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transition: transform 500ms ease;
    }
    .openNav .page-area {
        left: 0;
        transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0);
        transition: transform 500ms ease;
    }
    .page-area {
        left: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transition: transform 500ms ease;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav a {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 15px 10px !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        line-height: 16px !important;
        background-color: white;
        float: left !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
        width: 100%;
        text-transform: none !important;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        white-space: normal !important;
    }
    .navbar-nav li, .navbar-nav ul {
        padding: 0px !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }
    .open-panel {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 18px;
        right: 22px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        cursor: pointer;
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-color-on-scroll navbar-transparent hestia_left">
      <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <div class="title-logo-wrapper">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/wordpress/" title="">
       <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/cropped-hestia-header-2.jpg" alt=""></a>
     </div>
    </div>
         <div id="main-navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="menu-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-16 active"><a title="Home" href="http://localhost/wordpress">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a title="About Us" href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/">About Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-94"><a title="Sponsorship" href="http://localhost/wordpress/sponsorship/">Sponsorship</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-95"><a title="Blog" href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a title="Contact" href="http://localhost/wordpress/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
     </button>
        </div>

     </nav>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the objective? You want the navbar transparent on top and on scrolling it turns white?

Comment: can you post you html also?

Comment: Hi,

I just want to change the colour completely and remove the transparency in the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove Header Navbar From All or Selected Pages or Recolour Them

> Based on your comments:

To remove the navigation header from the theme to put your own one in, put this in your child theme css.

```
.navbar  {display:none;}
```

In this live view, I've added it to the custom CSS, but will also work in the child theme .css file.

*This removes the area from all pages. If you only want it removed on the home page, then only add the CSS to that page with this code:

```
.home .navbar  {display:none;}
```

To remove the background from other pages and the `box-shadow` use this code:

```
.navbar  {
    background:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

To change the nav background colour on pages, use this code:

```
.navbar  {
    background:#000;
}
```

or

```
.home .navbar  {
    background:#000;
}
```

Another way of removing the transparent homepage navigation header is like this:

```
.navbar.navbar-transparent {
    display: none;
}
```

To recolour the transparent area on the homepage red, use this:

```
.home .navbar.navbar-transparent{
    background-colour: #FF0000;
}
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you! .navbar  {
    background:#000;
} 
is working for all pages except for the home page where i think it is set to transparent. Is there a way to override the transparency or locate it in the parent theme?

Comment: Maybe add: .header-filter::before { background-color: none; } or .header-filter::before { display: none; } or .header-filter::before { background-color: #000; } or .header-filter::before { filter: none; }

Comment: hmm, those haven't worked for me. Could it be something to do with:

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav > li.active > a:after, .current-page-parent:after {
        height: 0 !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;

Comment: I've updated the answer with more info. This worked for me even when resizing for mobiles: .navbar.navbar-transparent {display: none;}

Comment: Hi, thanks, i've just added that and it has removed the entire navbar rather than just the transparency. Is there a way to remove the transparency applied to it? I've tried .navbar.navbar{color:red;} but that just makes the menu text red.

Comment: Did you want the navbar coloured? If so, rather than removing it, recolour it with this: .navbar.navbar-transparent {background-colour: #000;} That's black. Replace the hex with a colour of your choice. Red in hex is: #FF0000 https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/html-color-codes.html Use RGBA if you want alpha. Although you can use alpha in hex, it's hard to understand the value.

Comment: I've updated the answer with this info - We are getting there :)

Comment: That's done it! Brilliant, thanks so much for your help! :D

Comment: Wow, glad we got there. Was a lot of fun. It was a pleasure helping :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this code in your header.php file

```
if(is_home() || is_front_page()){
    ?>
    <style>
    .container{
        background-color:red;
    }
    </style>

<?php
}
```

replace this `header_element` class with your header element.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Do i need to copy the header.php file into my child theme to add this in?

Comment: yes. you need to copy the header.php file into child theme and add this css in.

Comment: you need to use this code with your container class